# How to import two DLLs with the same name (x86 and x64)?

Tags: dll, inno-setup, 32bit-64bit, pascalscript

When I import a function from two DLLs (one for 32-bits and another for 64-bits),  I get an error, is there an way to do that?

The code I tried is this:

```pascal
function DriverPackageInstallW(DriverPackageInfPath: Integer; Flags: Cardinal; pInstallerInfo: AnsiString ; pNeedReboot: Boolean): Cardinal;
external 'DriverPackageInstallW@files:difxapi_x86.dll';

function DriverPackageInstallW(DriverPackageInfPath: Integer; Flags: Cardinal; pInstallerInfo: AnsiString ; pNeedReboot: Boolean): Cardinal;
external 'DriverPackageInstallW@files:difxapi_x64.dll';
```

The error I received was this:

> Duplicate identifier 'DRIVERPACKAGEINSTALLW'

Answer (score 3):

To answer your *literal question*: You can import those functions under a different name into Inno Setup/Pascal Script.

```pascal
function DriverPackageInstallW_32(DriverPackageInfPath: Integer; Flags: Cardinal; pInstallerInfo: AnsiString ; pNeedReboot: Boolean): Cardinal;
external 'DriverPackageInstallW@files:difxapi_x86.dll';

function DriverPackageInstallW_64(DriverPackageInfPath: Integer; Flags: Cardinal; pInstallerInfo: AnsiString ; pNeedReboot: Boolean): Cardinal;
external 'DriverPackageInstallW@files:difxapi_x64.dll';
```

---

**But!** You cannot load 64-bit DLL into 32-bit Inno Setup process. That cannot work.

And in general, you cannot mix 32-bit and 64-bit code in one process.

---

If you need to call 64-bit DLL in Inno Setup (or in any 32-bit application), you will have to introduce a helper 64-bit EXE that loads and calls the DLL. You can execute that helper EXE in Inno Setup.

Comment: Martin, thanks for your clarification, I'll try that, I'm just afraid that the UAC (user account control), could appear two times during the installation..

Comment: No it should not. UAC is not required again, when running an application from already elevated application.